# Prevent low-score answers from being made Community Wiki

Tags: discussion, answers, community-wiki

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40213185/1669370) lately (as I was searching on Google for this very particular error).

As I was really disappointed with the current answer, I downvoteed it, without even noticing it was "Community Wiki".

Beyond the troll discussion which followed in the comments, I wonder what are exactly the point of "Community Wiki" answers.

I read this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts), which doesn't completely satisfy me.

If a user makes an insta-answer on a particular question (as it was the case here) and marks it as community wiki, it prevents other users to earn points by providing a better answer.

As earning points (and privileges) is (one of) the main incentive (s) to provide quality answers, such a practice is actually harmful to Stack Overflow quality.

**I think an answer should not be made community wiki before some quality threshold is reached** (let's say +10).

**[EDIT]** It seems that my question has been completely misunderstood.
I get what you all say.

- People don't chase for reputation. Good.
- CW answers make a good way for low-rep users to improve an existing answer. Good.
- Other people still can answer the question. Good.

But I don't get the point to make a CW answer with low quality.

Comment: _marks it as community wiki, it prevents other users to earn points by providing a better answer_ no.. It only prevents OP from earning/losing rep

Comment: well, what's the point of community wiki then? If it's not so store the reference answers?

Comment: It means OP no longer has to maintain the post.. The community can freely edit it. In this case the answerer has (mis)used the feature.

Comment: and no one earns point by doing that...

Comment: You also don't earn points when editing a normal answer...

Comment: Its not always about reputation points... contrary to what I am beginning to see is popular belief

Comment: `and no one earns point by doing that` The OP will neither gain nor lose points for that answer, exactly. Not sure what the problem is here? Someone posted an answer they didn't feel should earn points (because it basically just says "RTFM"). That is unorthodox but doesn't seem completely unreasonable, and I'm not seeing any "troll discussion", but... anyway. Nothing about this limits other answerers; they can provide a better answer and get votes for it.

Comment: Just read the user's profile, it explains why he now posts CW answers.  Please refrain from trolling the post owner with comments, that misses the point.

Comment: What's the difference between me answering with a high quality answer, and me answering with a high quality CW answer? Because in the second case the points don't come to me, that's an issue? they both "block" other answers as much

Comment: Wiki answer doesn't mean quality answer ... now if you think it's not a good one, update it to make it good

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I wonder what are exactly the point of "Community Wiki" answers.

It is a way of indicating that a post is not the work of one person, but rather a collaborative work of many people.  It both encourages others to edit the post (both by lowering the requirement for edits and to allow people to make edits that substantially change its content, unlike for non-CW posts) and is an acknowledgement that the answer is not "owned" by one person, but rather a group of people.  One small part of that is not rewarding the initial poster of the answer, because that answer is not just, or even primarily, their work.  Since no one has really figured out a way to "split" the reputation among the contributors in a fair and non-abusable way, the choice was made to just not give it to anyone.

> it prevents other users to earn points by providing a better answer.

No.  The existence of a CW answer doesn't stop anyone from posting their own answer. The *question* being a CW question prevents non-CW answers from being posted, but that's why only moderators can make a question CW these days, and that tends to be reserved for very rare circumstances in which it's *desirable* to not have additional people all posting their own answers.

> As earning points (and privileges) is (one of) the main incentive (s) to provide quality answers

In my experience the only people heavily incentivised by reputation are people not providing high quality content.  For people providing lots of valuable content it tends to be a very minor incentive at best.